# How to create an integer matrix from a picture

Tags: android, matrix, pixel

From a picture, I need to create a matrix table (example `1920*1080`) containing the light intensity of each pixel (for example : from 0 (black) to 10 (white)).
The pictures to analyse will be only pictures of the sky by night, looking for stars (so basically only black / white / grey will compose the picture).

What can I use to do it? The only thing I've found is to use the method `bitmap.getpixels()` to fill an array and compare the colors. But, I guess it's a wrong way.

I don't know if it's possible to directly get a light intensity of a pixel, do you have any ideas?
Do you have any suggestions concerning the way to do it ? 
Thanks a lot by advance.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I do think that you should perform a conversion from the colour space RGB to HSI

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm gonna check this way.